# a command that kill gnome-shell and again run it when consume cpu with cpulimit

Tags: gnome-shell, kill, cpulimit

I want to create a command with cpulimit that kill and restore gnome-shell process when it consume 20 percent of cpu.
with this line i can kill: `sudo cpulimit -e gnome-shell -l 20 -k`
but I want to kill and again start gnome-shell .

Comment: Killing gnome-shell will also kill all desktop processes, lose all unsaved work, and kick you back to a login prompt. "again start gnome-shell" would require logging in again.

Comment: Rather than using `cpulimit`, I suggest using the `nice` command (`man nice`), adjusting the processes' priorities,  and let the system scheduler handle things. Also, do you have swap space?